# get list of entities in doctype of xml file

Tags: python, lxml

Using python and lxml, is there a way to get a list of the entities in the doctype of an xml file?
Here is the shrunken down xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dmodule [
<!ENTITY somegraphic1 SYSTEM 'somegraphic1.cgm' NDATA cgm>
<!ENTITY somegraphic2 SYSTEM 'somegraphic2.cgm' NDATA cgm>
<!NOTATION cgm SYSTEM 'cgm'>
<!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC 'ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML' 'http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-1/ent/xml/ISOEntities'>
%ISOEntities;]>
<dmodule>
<graphic ident="somegraphic1"/>
<graphic ident="somegraphic2"/>
</dmodule>
```

Can I parse the file with lxml and retrieve the listed entities (!ENTITY) in the doctype?
I want the list of graphic files used with an eventual result of ['somegraphic1.cgm', 'somegraphic2.cgm'].
Currently, the code (inelegantly) just opens the xml file and reads line by line until `<dmodule` and then splits the lines looking for string ending with '.cgm' - yuck.
If lxml can not, please recommend another way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, there's a somewhat strange way to get there and it works at least with your stripped down xml above - so if it fits your needs, it may be good enough...

```
myx = """[your xml snippet]"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(myx,'html.parser') #yup, html parser...
for i in soup:           
    if 'ENTITY' in i and 'SYSTEM' in i:
        one = i.split('SYSTEM')
        two = one[1].split('NDATA')
        print(two[0])
```

Output:

> somegraphic1.cgm
>
> somegraphic2.cgm

Answer (score 1):

libxml2 has a function [xmlGetDocEntity(doc, name)](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-entities.html#xmlGetDocEntity) which returns an object representing the entity, with a field [URI](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlEntity) containing the unparsed entity URI. This is what I used for a tool that does something similar: https://github.com/kibook/s1kd-tools/tree/master/tools/s1kd-refs.

Example usage:

```
$ s1kd-refs --icn DMC-[...].XML
somegraphic1.cgm
somegraphic2.cgm
```

I use an XPath expression like "//@infoEntityIdent" to get a list of all the graphics used, then fetch the entity URI for each one. Note that this does not list all the ENTITYs declared in the DTD, only those actually used as `<graphic>`s or `<symbol>`s within the XML.

lxml is built on top of libxml2, but I'm not familiar enough with it to know if there is an exact equivalent to xmlGetDocEntity.

Another option would be to first use XSLT to create something simpler to parse:

```xml
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <graphics>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//@infoEntityIdent"/>
      </graphics>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@infoEntityIdent">
      <graphic>
        <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-entity-uri(.)"/>
      </graphic>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Output:

```xml
<graphics>
  <graphic>somegraphic1.cgm</graphic>
  <graphic>somegraphic2.cgm</graphic>
</graphics>
```